# How to load multiple files from azure blob to azure synapse(Dw) by using azuredatafactory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-container-service, azure-synapse

I am trying to load multiple files from azure blob to azure sql dw by using azure data factory.Below is my code.And I am facing the highlighted error.Could anyone suggest.
I am pasting my adf code json here.

I am getting below Highlighted at copy activity stage.

```
{
    "name": "DelimitedText11",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage2",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "FileName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "fileName": {
                    "value": "@dataset().FileName",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "container": "input"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": ""
        },
        "schema": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

Error:

```
{
        "errorCode": "2200",
        "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorMissingPropertyInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Required property 'fileName' is missing in payload.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
        "failureType": "UserError",
        "target": "Copy data1",
        "details": []
    }
```

Comment: Hi Imran, could you post some more information? Data Factory is primarily a visual environment, so some screen shots may be useful. A best guess is that the fileName for the DataSet is not being set properly prior to this activity.

Comment: Hi joel, i wish to add screen shot but community not allowing to paste screenshots of my whole code,if you know other way please tell me i am happy to share screen shots

Answer (score 1):

If you want load multiple files from azure blob to Azure SQL Data Warehouse, please must set the `Wildcard file path` in Source dataset. Or you will always get the error 2200:

```
{
        "errorCode": "2200",
        "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorMissingPropertyInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Required property 'fileName' is missing in payload.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
        "failureType": "UserError",
        "target": "Copy data1",
        "details": []
    }
```

For example,  I have two csv files with same schema and load them to my Azure SQL Data Warehouse table `test`.

**Csv files:**

[image]

**Source Dataset:**

[image]

**Source setting: choose all the csv files in source container:**

[image].

**Sink dataset:**

[image]

**Sink settings:**

[image]

**Mapping:**
[image]

**Settings:**
[image]

**Execute the pipeline and check the data in the ADW:**
[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon Yue,Could you provide full information for loading data from azure blob to azure dw .    Ex:emp.csv has to load in emp table, dept.csv has to load in dept.table.by datafactory

Comment: @Imran I just figure out how to load multiple files to one ADW table. Still testing foreach active to create table now.

Comment: Let me know once you done Bro, I will also try my side.

Comment: @Imran Ok. But please ask question more clearly next time. Can you post another question? I answered how load multiple csv files to one ADW table. Still not sure how to answer you the next question. You should tell us  which one you want, load csv files to create table or mapping to the exist table in ADW.

Comment: Hi Yue, the below is my requirement..in my blob emp.csv ,dept.csv, and sales.csv files are there.i am trying to load in sql dw as                            
     emp.csv---->dbo.emp(table),,                                                               
 dept.csv---->dbo.dept(table)                                                                    
 sales.csv---->dbo.sales(table).I hope this gives you clear information.
Here what i am trying is :
emp1.csv-----> dbo.emp1 table

dept.csv---->dbo.dept table

sales.csv---->dbo.sales

the above are dummy names,but requirement is same

Comment: @Imran I'm now test using get matadata and foreach active to copy the csv files.

Comment: Hi Yue, could I connect you  by email or  Linkedin.

Comment: @Imran Sorry, I can't tell you. I haven't succeed now.  I called Azure support, they will also tested it and contact with ADF PG. Next Monday or Tuesday,  we could get the answer. Please wait my update.

Comment: @Yue,What is this ADF PG.

Comment: Data Factory Product Team

Comment: @Imran I figured out it. Please see the answer in you another question. Can you please also accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.